# How to compute $E[1/x]$, where the process is described by $dx = ax\,dt + b\,dw$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, expected-value

I am quite new to stochastict calculus and probability and therefore my question may be naive.

I have a process described by $dx= ax\,dt + b\,dw$ and I would like to compute $\operatorname E\left[\dfrac{1}{x_t}\right]$.

Can anyone give me some hints on how proceed (even numerically)?

Comment: It doesn't exist, since $X_t$ has positive density at zero.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a bit perplex. Having a positive densitty at zero would bring the process towards 0 (if a<0). But for high values of t, would it not be possible to take a set of realisations sample them a T>>t0, invert them and compute the mean?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. As I said, for some $c>0$,  $\mathrm{E}[1/|X_t|] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f_{X_t}(x)}{|x|}dx\ge   c\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \frac{1}{|x|}dx = +\infty$.

Comment: Are you sure about your SDE though? Shouldn't it be $dX = aXdt + bXdW$ ?